# Archive files in EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, archive

I want to create the archives of the files in EC2 instance to load them into the S3 bucket, but I am not getting a proper command to run on the AWS cli.

Answer (score 0):

Upload to S3 Bucket: `aws s3 cp archive.tar.gz s3://your-s3-bucket/ --region your-s3region`